# How to open file path within workbook for Vlookup reference

Tags: excel, vba

When I press on the macro. It opens the browser to choose the file that VLOOKUP reference  from instead of opening the reference within then apply the VLOOKUP. I am new to VBA help appreciated.

``````
    With Original
        
       Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
       Range("C1").Value = "Admin_Vlookup"
      
        rec_range = getColRangeFunction("Admin_Vlookup")
        Range(rec_range).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,'[Pairing List.xlsx]Recruiting_Admins'!$A$1:$B$33, 2,0)"
        Range(rec_range).Select
    
    ''~~> open the workbook and pass it to workbook object variable Working on Improvement
       lookup_reference = "C:\Users\aayoub2026\Desktop\BG Training DOCSS\Pairing List.xlsx"
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(lookup_reference)
        wb.Sheets("Recruiting_Admins").Select


`````
``````

Comment: You should open the workbook first. Why do you attempt `Range(rec_range).Formula` before the `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(lookup_reference)`?

Comment: I don't want to open pairing list everytime I am adding a column with the vlookup. I want it to open the reference within then add vlookup column in current workbook

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Maybe you should try writing the formula with the entire path to the workbook and avoid opening the workbook at all.

Comment: Can you show me example

Comment: Open the file first and then add the formula?